# Музыкальный плеер  Delphi

Tags: delphi

Добрый день как в Delphi реализовать что бы при добавлении музыки в плеер добавил все музыкальные файлы имеющиеся в этой папке и подпапки в listbox

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете получить список файлов из директории по определенной маске при помощи `FindFirst` и `FindNext`. А потом уже используйте по своему усмотрению.